# How to auto direct to my web application in Apache http server?

Tags: apache, web, server, web-hosting

I have my web application hosted on apache server. When I hit my url i.e my ip address - xxx.xx.xxx.12 apache's web page pops up. 
So my app url is - xxx.xx.xxx.12/mywebapp.

Now what I did is I have mapped DNS to my ip xxx.xx.xxx.12.

so when ever I hit my new url "abc.com" . My apache home page is shown.

But I want when I hit this url, my web application should come up. 
That mean when I hit my url /mywebapp should automatically append to my url.

Where I do this setting in my apache server. How do I set its context ?

Comment: Do you have access to apache `.conf` files?

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 - Add a redirection script**

You have to edit the default apache page, and add a redirection.

Simply replace your index.html file with this line, and it will redirect to /mywebapp:

```html
<script>location='/mywebapp';</script>
```

Where is the default index.html located ?

If you are using Apache for Linux: /var/www/

If you are using Apache for Windows: C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/

**Method 2 - Edit your httpd.conf file**

This way you can make the folder /mywebapp as the root of the web server

Locate the file httpd.conf

And then perform a search for the DocumentRoot directive

For instance:

```html
DocumentRoot /home/www
```

Change to

```html
DocumentRoot /home/user/mywebapp
```

And then restart your webserver.